# All elements that are not ".time" should have font open sans, 400px, color:#333333, with the line-height of 1.6

Tags: html, css, fonts

I wrote the code below for my website, but when I have it written like that, the website seems to understand the "Courier New" bit for the "time" portion of the code, but it doesn't seem to understand the commands for the fonts that are not time components. It doesn't seem to process any of the `body {margin-bottom: 16px; font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.6; color: #333333; }` bit of the code. (I basically am trying to get all the fonts for contents, that are not "time," to be open sans, 400px, color:#333333, with the line-height of 1.6.) Is there an issue with my code below? Help! Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body .time {
font-family: "Courier New" } body {margin-bottom: 16px; font-family: Open Sans; font-weight: 400; 
font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.6; color: #333333; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Weekdays <span class="time">10:00~18:00</span></p>
<p>Saturdays <span class="time">10:00~13:30</span></p>
<p>(we are closed on holidays.)</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.time {
font-family: "Courier New" ;
  color:green;
  } 
body {margin-bottom: 16px; 
  font-family: Open Sans; 
  font-weight: 400; 
font-size: 16px; 
  line-height: 1.6; 
  color: #333333; 
  } 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Weekdays <span class="time">10:00~18:00</span></p>
<p>Saturdays <span class="time">10:00~13:30</span></p>
<p>(we are closed on holidays.)</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS `:not` selector like this, hope it would help-

```
*:not(.time) {
  font-family: open sans;
  font-size: 400px;
  color:#333333;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.time {
 /* CSS for .time here */
}
```

Comment: @Johannes What you're saying here is the exact opposite of what is asked in this question

Comment: That is really why you got the downvotes, try to think differently

Comment: No, I didn't mean that, I meant you got downvotes because of how you think, and you just proved it again, that's why I told you to think differently